# Is the determination of the constituents within a sentence without exception nonambiguous?

Tags: syntax, constituents

Is there always one unique way to partition a sentence into its constituents or, like in the following picture, is it possible to analyze a sentence into parts several different ways?

[image: rows of dots indicating words with red underlines representing parts of sentences]

The three rows of dots represent the same sentence, and the red underlines represent constituents, such as a noun phrase, compound verb, or prepositional phrase.

Comment: -1 As indicated by a comment to one of your [previous questions](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9392/is-there-something-in-linguistics-that-could-be-described-by-a-layman-as-part-o), 'part of sentence' is not a standard term. Please see this comment, and adjust your terminology. Otherwise people can't answer your questions...

Comment: There's **always** an ambiguity. [Time flies like an arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_flies_like_an_arrow;_fruit_flies_like_a_banana#Analysis_of_the_basic_ambiguities) --> *Each of a type of flying insect, "time-flies," individually enjoys a different arrow (similar comparison applies)*.

Comment: @robert In meireikei-ese, "part of sentence" is to constituents as "part of speech" is to individual words. I have suggested an edit to standardize the terms.

Comment: In written language there is always ambiguity because it only represents a small part of the actual signal. Anybody who's built a parser knows that it's hard to get a program to distinguish a normal parse from a ridiculous but possible alternative parse that's allowed by the rules. In speech ambiguity is much rarer.

Answer (score 3):

The way one analyses a sentence and divides it into parts depends on the system of analysis one uses. The sentence that follows, for example, can be divided in several ways:

The old man hit the young girl with a thin cane.

[The old man] [hit the young girl with a thin cane.]

[The old man]  [[hit] [the young girl with a thin cane.]]

[The old man] [[hit] [the young girl {with a thin cane}.]]

[The old man] [[hit] [the young girl] {/with/ a thin cane}.]]

... and so on.

Comment: could you give me a name for one of those systems of analysis?

Comment: @meirekei - Sorry, I can't. This is not my field. Doubtless somebody else will come along soon with some labels.

Comment: This is almost a good answer.  The example is divided into constituents differently, depending on its interpretation (regardless of what system of analysis is used).  If "with a thin cane" helps identify which girl is meant, then "the young girl with a thin cane" is a constituent.  But if "with a thin cane" tells what instrument was used to hit her, instead, "hit the young girl with a thin cane" is a constituent.  So the answer to the question is no, there is not always one unique way of dividing a sentence into parts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is decidedly **NO** -- there is not always a unique way to partition a sentence into its constituents -- and this is so however one defines "constituent."  This is so because some sentences are inherently **ambiguous**: they have more than one syntactic reading, and so can be represented by different sets of constituents.  The example used in the other answer is a case in point: *"The old man hit the girl with a cane."*

The ambiguity: did the man have the cane or did the girl?  This is not specified in the sentence.  (We may happen to know the answer, but it does not come from **syntactic** information.  It might be found elsewhere in the discourse, or it might be based on our pragmatic knowledge -- old men are more likely to have canes than girls, etc. -- but it is not coded in **this** sentence itself.)

Two classic kinds of syntactic theories are phrase-structure grammars (PSG) and dependency grammars (DG).  Both represent the sentence as a tree.  In PSG, the internal nodes of the tree name "constituents", and one leaf of the tree corresponds to one word in the sentence.  In DG each node in the tree corresponds to a word in the sentence, and we say that each node "depends" on its immediate parent node (i.e., the child depends on its parent).

Constituents: we must define what we mean by that -- the more appropriate way to analyze the sentence is a tree.  Given a tree, we can speak of constituents by equating the notion of a constituent with the notion of a **subtree**.  So if we say that each subtree forms one constituent, then your question makes sense.

Finally, note, that constituents are always nested, so your picture is oversimplified --- it shows no nesting.

Now, independently of y/our preferred theory, one could see our example as having constituents:

A. *[ The old man ]      [ hit     [ the girl [ with a cane ] ]    ].*

**or**

B. *[ The old man ]      [ hit    [ the girl ]   [ with a cane ]    ].*

In A, *[ with a cane ]*  modifies the GIRL (e.g., in DP terms, it depends on the node GIRL).  It tells us which girl was hit: the one with the cane, and not the one with the ice-cream.

In B, *[ with a cane ]* modifies HIT (in DP terms, it depends on HIT), and tells us exactly how she was hit: with a cane, and not with an oxygen bag.

This kind of ambiguity (and many others) is what makes analysis of natural language challenging --- not so for computer languages, where ambiguity is absent by design.